# Numpy array to CV image in CV2 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv3.0

I have a numpy array. How can I convert it to an image type that cv2 can manipulate in OpenCV 3.0? Ex:

```
smaller = np.empty([h, w])
image = np.zeros_like(smaller)
cv2.fillPoly(image, [cnt], 255)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image, 1, math.pi/90, 2, None, 30, 1);
```

Results in

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (image.type() == CV_8UC1) in HoughLinesProbabilistic, file /tmp/opencv320150728-16719-neh6hn/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp, line 424`

Comment: the Error shows that you need a 8 bit unsigned int array.

Comment: try `lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(np.uint8(image), 1, math.pi/90, 2, None, 30, 1);`